# Apply a custom theme to Caldroid Calendar

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am developing an Android app with a calendar view. I am using Caldroid library for the calendar view and now i want to apply a dark theme to my calendar. I tried the solution given in the github caldroid page. But I failed to apply the theme. Bellow errors raised from my styles.xml

> error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'CaldroidDefault'. error: Error: No resource
>   found that matches the given name: attr 'styleCaldroidGridView'.
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'styleCaldroidMonthName'. error: Error: No resource found that matches
>   the given name: attr 'styleCaldroidNormalCell'.error: Error: No
>   resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'styleCaldroidSquareCell'. error: Error: No resource found that
>   matches the given name: attr 'styleCaldroidViewLayout'. error: Error
>   retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given
>   name 'CaldroidDefaultMonthName'. error: Error retrieving parent for
>   item: No resource found that matches the given name
>   'CaldroidDefaultGridView'. error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name 'CaldroidDefaultCell'.
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'CaldroidDefault'. error: Error: No resource
>   found that matches the given name: attr 'styleCaldroidGridView'.
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'styleCaldroidMonthName'. error: Error: No resource found that matches
>   the given name: attr 'styleCaldroidNormalCell'. error: Error: No
>   resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'styleCaldroidSquareCell'. Error: No resource found that matches the
>   given name: attr 'styleCaldroidViewLayout'. Error retrieving parent
>   for item: No resource found that matches the given name
>   'CaldroidDefaultMonthName'. error: Error retrieving parent for item:
>   No resource found that matches the given name
>   'CaldroidDefaultGridView'. error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name 'CaldroidDefaultCell'.

In my activity it also raised below errors when i applied the theme as it

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(CaldroidFragment.THEME_RESOURCE, com.caldroid.R.style.CaldroidDefaultDark);
    caldroidFragment.setArguments(args);
```

Errors:

> Multiple markers at this line
>     - CaldroidDefaultDark cannot be resolved or is       not a field
>     - THEME_RESOURCE cannot be resolved or is not    a field

If anyone can help me out, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check this library: https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview it's an easily customizable calendar and unlike caldroid it runs smoothly even on low-end devices, you can find all the information about customizing it in the README.md and the sample

Comment: thanks for your reply and I have done lot of development with caldroid calendar in my app. In this situation it is very difficult to move to another library. I just want to change its colors to end up the app development and much appreciate if you can give me help for that purpose.